# How to share a library globally in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For example, there's `styled-components` library, what if i want to use it in 10 components, i would have to import it 10 times? Or HOC is the only way to deal with that?

I'm doing this in my ExampleComponent:

```
import styled from 'styled-components`;
```

Then i can use it, i need an example with HOC approach or something better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ... i would have to import it 10 times?

Only if the components are all defined in their own modules, and they all need to use `styled-components`. You have to import once per *module*, not once per component. There's no requirement that each component be written in its own module, doing so (or not) is a matter of style.

As [Dan Abramov said](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/1220029098543788032):

> I still get surprised that “one function per file” is clearly unnecessary but “one component per file” is somehow a common practice!

In any case, don't worry: You only have one copy of the library. The `import` is just binding the modules together, not actually copying the module you import from into your module.

Comment: > Only if the components are all defined in their own modules. For example, if i have a Parent component, then i'm using Child1, Child2, Child3 component in it, then i wouldn't need to import `styled-components` in a childs?

Comment: @AlexanderKim - When you do `import styled from "styled-components";` you're doing three things: 1. Making `styled-components` a dependency of your module. 2. Triggering the load of `styled-components` if it's not already loaded. 3. Assigning its default export to the identifer `styled`. You only need to do that when you need to use `styled` in a component in that module. Where you *use* the component doesn't matter. It's whether the component needs to use that identifier. If `styled` isn't in the code of the component, it doesn't need it.

Comment: @AlexanderKim - I don't think Vue vs. React comes into it. This is about how JavaScript modules work.

Comment: I understand how JS modules work. I meant: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html, Vue has a method to globally use a library, you just import in an entry file and fire `Vue.use(importedLibrary)`. I was looking for the same in React, but it seems, there's nothing similar to it.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want a HOC. You can do something like:

```
import styled from 'styled-components`;

const Wrapper = styled.section`
  padding: 4em;
  background: papayawhip;
`;

const withWrapper = component => {
  return <Wrapper>{component}</Wrapper>
}

export default withWrapper;
```

And then use it as:

```
const Home = () => {
  return <h1>Home</h1>
}

export default withWrapper(Home);
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: ...at which point you have to import the wrapper just as many times as you would have had to import `styled-components`. There may be *other* reasons for using a HOC, but avoiding repeated `import`s isn't one of them.

Comment: Yes, you are right @T.J.Crowder. But i wrote so because he asked for that if someone can show him a way of doing it with HOC.

Comment: Thank you for an example, indeed, now i would need to use this wrapper in every component that requires styled-components, lol